# Creating Pop Ups On Click With Highcharts Map

Tags: r, highcharts, maps

I'm creating a map of counties in Michigan using Highcharts. My code so far is below:

```
hcmap(  
"countries/us/us-mi-all",   
data = dataframe,   
value = "distance",   
joinBy = c("name", "county"),   
name = "Distance",   
dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, format = "{point.name}"),   
borderColor = "#FAFAFA",   b
orderWidth = 0.1,   
tooltip = list(pointFormat = "<b>{point.name}</b> <br><br> <b>Distance</b>: {point.value:.1f} Miles <br><b>Total</b>: {point.n_total}")) |>  
hc_title(text="<b>Distance by County</b>", style=list(color="#FAFAFA", useHTML=TRUE, fontSize='25px'))
```

I am hosting the map on an R Shiny dashboard and want to create popups that appear on the same page with additional information about each county when the user clicks on a county on the map (this info is stored in other columns of the dataframe). The pop ups in this map are exactly what I'm looking for (although with a table of info rather than the pie chart) but I am having trouble converting it to my code: https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/

I have tried using the jsfiddle link above and also tried to use the plotOptions argument to create pop ups that appear on click, but I haven't been able to make it work. I keep getting a "object 'Series' is not found" error whenever I try to use plotOptions. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Hi, your jsfiddle doesn't work, could you please share it again? ;)

Comment: Yes! The jsfiddle is from this example posted by Highcharts https://www.highcharts.com/demo/maps/data-class-two-ranges

Comment: I am not the r developer, so I can only help you with JS code, however what is important to mention, the popup is triggered by `series.point` click event, so you need to implement it to your code.
https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/plotOptions.series.point.events.click 
You mentioned about using the plotOptions but don't see it in the code, ould you please share it?

Comment: Of course, sorry I am new to posting. I have tried adding the following code as an initial test to just create a click event, but I get an error saying "object: Series' not found"

```hc_plotOptions:{
series:{
events:{
click: function(event){
alert(this.name + 'clicked')
}
}
}
}```

Answer (score 1):

I've recreated an example using sample data used in the `highcharter` package documentation.

```
mapdata <- get_data_from_map(download_map_data("custom/usa-and-canada"))

data_fake <- mapdata |>
  select(code = `hc-a2`) |>
  mutate(value = 1e5 * abs(rt(nrow(mapdata), df = 10)))

hcmap(
  "custom/usa-and-canada",
  data = data_fake,
  value = "value",
  joinBy = c("hc-a2", "code"),
  name = "Fake data",
  dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, format = "{point.name}"),
  borderColor = "#FAFAFA",
  borderWidth = 0.1,
  allowPointSelect = TRUE,
  tooltip = list(
    valueDecimals = 2,
    valuePrefix = "$",
    valueSuffix = "USD"
  )
) |> hc_plotOptions(
  series = list(
    events = list(
      click = JS(
        "function(event){ alert(this.name + ' clicked') }"
      )
    )
  )
)
```

The key is to substitute each curly brace instance with `list()` and then R can accept JavaScript in the function as long as it's enclosed with `JS()` and the actual JavaScript is passed as a character by surrounding it with double quotation marks, e.g., `JS("custom JavaScript here")`. However, this click event does not replicate the example jsfiddle link you provided. You may need to substitute with the JavaScript function used in the example, and tailor as needed to your data set.

Comment: Just to add to that, in the Highcharts example, the click happens on `series.point`, not on the series itself. It's not a mistake, but it's good to know it might make things a bit different.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I am new to both R and Highcharts (all previous experience has been with Python) and using JS in R scripts has been really confusing for me. This is awesome, thank you